# Data binding is not working in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to ask if there is something like ObservableCollection but for object in WPF C#.

Here is my problem:

I have following `Grid` in XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="detailsGrid">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
   <TextBox Text="{Binding Excerpt, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
</Grid>
```

In my code behind I set the DataContext of `detailsGrid` to object of following class:

```
recipeDetails = new RecipeDetailsContainer();
this.detailsGrid.DataContext = recipeDetails;
```

`RecipeDetailsContainer` class:

```
public class RecipeDetailsContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set 
        { 
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _excerpt;
    public string Excerpt
    {
        get { return _excerpt; }
        set
        {
            _excerpt = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Excerpt");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In other class method I want to write this info to WPF window, so I set:

```
private void PrintInfoAboutRecipe(object sender, RecipeHandlerArgs e)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => 
    {
        if (e.Container != null && e.Container.Recipe != null)
        {
            this.recipeDetails.Name = e.Container.Recipe.Name;
            this.recipeDetails.Excerpt = e.Container.Recipe.Excerpt;
        }
        else
        {
            this.recipeDetails.Name = "";
            this.recipeDetails.Excerpt = "";
        }
    }));
}
```

But my binding does not work and nothing is showed in TextBlocks.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid x:Name="detailsGrid">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <TextBox  Text="{Binding Name}" />
   <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Excerpt}" />
</Grid>
```

Try to add your TextBoxes in Columns, because they are at same place. Second try to initialize your properties in the class constructor.

```
public class RecipeDetailsContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public RecipeDetailsContainer() {
    Name = string.Empty;
    Excerpt = string.Empty;
  }
```

Further Information about BindingMode can be found here:

[Binding.Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Dispatcher**

It could be that you have to `Dispatcher.Current.Invoke()` the sets of your Properties. If you set them from a different thread the binding Fails.

Comment: Nothing changed after adding `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`

Comment: you also changed ` <TextBox Grid.Column="1"`?

Comment: is `e.Container.Recipe.Name` filled with a value ? maybe this is empty

Comment: Yes, I also changed `<TextBox Grid.Column="1"...`
 I am 100 % sure the value is there :-P

Comment: is `e.Container.Recipe.Name` filled with a value ? maybe this is empty ... Did you get a silent Binding Expression error in Visual Studio Output ?

Comment: I see what is the problem: `else` part of setting the TextBlocks. When I remove it, text shows. Maybe it was because of fast property changing but that's strange :-P

Comment: ah okay :) that behavior was not to see by me :P

Comment: -1 for suggesting *Try to add `Mode=TwoWay`* when the `TextBox.Text` Property has the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata.BindsTwoWayByDefault` enumeration set on it. However, I'd be happy to remove this down vote if you remove that incorrect suggestion from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming datacontext, vm etc is correct:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitons>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- empty space, not sure how you want your gui
        but your boxes would overlap in your example -->
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <!-- updates binding on vm/datacontext on each keypress -->
  <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" /> 
  <!-- updates binding on vm/datacontext when focus is lost -->
  <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Excerpt, Mode=TwoWay" />
</Grid>
```

The UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged is a bit paranoid, the default is the the binding updates your viewmodel once the text box looses behaviour. From the little I know from your example I would dropped it. The two way binding is important in control where you want to both be able to update a Property/DP, both from the GUI and the VM.

You have somtething called [the WPF cheatsheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf), it's old but there you have most you need about bindings in one very compact place. When learning WPF I had document stuck to the wall behind my computer @ work, home & school when learning WPF.

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: Thanks, that cheatsheet will be usefull :-)